# Creating a Module for IIS 7.*

Tags: iis-7, module

I currently am attempting to create a UI Module for IIS.  I plan on using it on IIS 7 and up.

I have followed several different tutorials.

I used the source from this link for testing after it failed to work the first time.
[Creating a UI Module For IIS7 to watch Current Requests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/08/28/creating-a-ui-module-for-iis7-to-watch-current-requests.aspx)

I did more looking here
[How to Create a Simple IIS Manager Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/269/how-to-create-a-simple-iis-manager-module/)

My end goal is to have a button within IIS (as it is in the first link).

I am getting the assembly into the GAC (`%windir%/assembly`), I checked that.
I then added

```
<add name="CurrentRequestsUI" type="CurrentRequestsUI.RequestModuleProvider, CurrentRequestsUI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=269f1cc1a4bf892b" />
```

within the moduleProviders section of my administration.config (%windir%/System32/inetsrv/config)

then added `<add name="CurrentRequestsUI" />` in the modules section of the same file.

Right now I'm just using sample source to see if I can get that to work before I start my project.  I apologize for if I'm posting this in the wrong place.  If you want me to provide more information, ask and I will provide it.

My question is how do I add a custom UI Module to IIS?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the question? I'm not sure I followed.

Comment: How do I add a UI module to IIS?  when I follow the tutorials and examples they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had been editing the `administration.config` file within Visual Studio and Notepad++ (32-bit applications), but I then opened the 'same' file within Notepad (64-bit application).  Making changes within Notepad made the changes within the proper file.

Opening 32-bit applications such as Notepad++ and Visual Studio 2010 opened the wrong file

```
%windir%/SysWOW64/inetsrv/administration.config
```

Opening 64-bit applications such as Notepad opened the correct file

```
%windir%/System32/inetsrv/administration.config
```